# How to pass data through hashrouter with random generated search?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I got a random generated search hash router and I don't know how pass state to it. Here is what I tried so far.

```
<Link to={`/mahjongGame?roomCode=${randomCodeGenerator(4)}`} state={{ dataForm:data }}><button className="game-button yellow" >Confirm2</button></Link>
```

This is the route path.

```
<Route path='/mahjongGame' exact component={MahjongGame} />
```

This is the result of `console.log(props.location)` in the routed page

```
{pathname: '/mahjongGame', search: '?roomCode=wYTj', hash: '', state: undefined, key: 'ab5in5'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you are logging location with props.location. But I tried this and it works,

```
  const location = useLocation();
  const dataForm = location.state?.dataForm || null;
```

Comment: I tried before. It doesn't work. Maybe it's because hashRouter doesn't support props.state when routing to another page. I am thinking of using Browsing Router to  do that.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-keller-lrwflr?file=/src/App.js  take a look. It is working, or could be that i misunderstood something in you question. Sorry about the messy code!

Comment: I need to use search in my routing, the expected result should be like this:  `{pathname: '/mahjongGame', search: '?roomCode=610mo', hash: '', state: {…}, key: 
'51ka0l'}`    But I found that if I  use the following code, the page need to refresh first to see the page, otherwise it's blank page.  
`<Link to={{pathname: `/mahjongGame?roomCode=${randomCodeGenerator(5)}`, state: settingForm }}>`